# Projections of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given a random vector **X** with the multivariate normal distribution F(**X**), we know that, for two vectors **a** and **b**, the projections $A=\sum_j a_j X_j $  and  $B=\sum_i b_i X_i $ are univariate normal.

I'm interested in the joint distribution of A and B. Is their joint distribution normal? Is the dependence between A and B described only by their correlation? (do they have only linear dependence?) 
Thank you for any insight. References are highly appreciated as well.

Comment: I found the answer for the above question and I thought is nice to share it. So the answer is yes: A and B are joint normal and so the relation between them is determined by the correlation. This is due to the properties of the characteristic function of a multivariate normal.

Answer (score 3):

The vector (A,B) consisting of two scalars is a "two-dimensional projection" of the multivairate normal vector X. More generally, if you multiply X with any matrix such that you get a new vector with dimension <= than the original dimension of X, you again get a multivariate normal vector. That is, all the components of the new vector will be normal, and their dependence is determined only by their correlations.

Comment: Yes, @Leonid indeed. It would of been nice if you could give the answer before I did. See above.

Comment: The condition that the "new vector (has) dimension <= than the original dimension" is unnecessary and irrelevant.